# Set Logo to Paypal

Tags: c#, paypal, xamarin.forms, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented Paypal payment functionality in my xamarin-forms application. I have used paypal express checkout. Now I want to set logo when paypal webpage popup. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This [**LINK**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/#id0863B0L805Z) should provide you with the info you need to customize the landing page. Search for "Custom Page Style"

Basically you just need to include the following key-value pair in your SetExpressCheckout api call:

**LOGOIMG**={your url image location}

**CARTBORDERCOLOR**={6-digit hexadecimal color}

You can also make some custom pages and save them. Basically log into your paypal account and go here: https://www.paypal.com/fi/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-page-styles

Comment: I am using **https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1** api  to complete paypal payment functionality @CCamilo

Comment: I am using Express Checkout REST integration .

Comment: Well, those parameters should be added in the request. I assume same way you add, for example, the amount to pay. Which SDK are you using (PHP, JAVA, ...)?

Comment: In any case you can try also the second approach, go here https://www.paypal.com/fi/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-page-styles and customize your pages.